# Which Property do I need to edit, to change following Color?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, chart.js, styling

Chart.js Radar Chart
[image]

I have a Radar Chart like this, which Property do i need to edit to change the Color of the highlighted Lines? I already tried: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#angle-line-options (color) but that didn't do the trick..
I already changed the Color of the "normal" Grid, so that isn't a problem anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on if you are using the new v3 or old v2 version of the lib you will have to configure it in a sligtly different place, see both examples underneath for both versions to see how you can do this:

V3:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        grid: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.0.2/chart.js" integrity="sha512-n8DscwKN6+Yjr7rI6mL+m9nS4uCEgIrKRFcP0EOkIvzOLUyQgOjWK15hRfoCJQZe0s6XrARyXjpvGFo1w9N3xg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

V2:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      gridLines: {
        color: 'red'
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js" integrity="sha512-hZf9Qhp3rlDJBvAKvmiG+goaaKRZA6LKUO35oK6EsM0/kjPK32Yw7URqrq3Q+Nvbbt8Usss+IekL7CRn83dYmw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```